# NativeScript auto scaling label or label font

Tags: fonts, label, font-size, scaling, nativescript

How can i make my `Nativescript` android layout label scale font based on screen width.

I don't want it to wrap text on multiple lines.

In **iOS** there's `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` but how can I get same feature on **Android**.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't worry about handling font-size for each screen because NativeScript ***only supports device-independent units*** (as menitoned [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#supported-css-properties))
When you set your font-size CSS property it will render its value depending on the device size/resolution.

However in order to have responsive UX for multiple screens you should 
arrange your layout os it can be rendered as espected on different devices.
To achive that take a look at this [article about supporting multiple screens](https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/supporting-multiple-screens)
Once your layout is set the font-size will be handled by the device-independent units and will look and feel just as intended.
If you want to try this out simply create the template project (**tns create myApp**) and run it on different emulators.

Comment: No I mean a situation where I get data string and I don't want to use textwrap. I mean adjusting label font dynamically based on text size.

Comment: No worries no more. Handled this by creating different layout for each common screen dpi. But still this thing is on native ios so it would be cool on android too "scaling label".

Comment: This post is a bit old, but take a look at this post: http://nuvious.com/Blog/2015/5/9/creating-a-scalable-label-in-nativescript